# How to generate a reference key between rows

Tags: mysql, index

I would like to group rows under a reference number.

My current approach is this:

```
CREATE TABLE `txn` (
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `reference` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

SET @ref := (SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * 9999999999) AS ref FROM txn WHERE "ref" NOT IN (SELECT reference FROM txn) LIMIT 1);

-- They belong together 
INSERT INTO txn (reference) VALUES (@ref), (@ref);
```

This seems to work fine. The only concern is that I have to dump CSV files with around 50 to 100 thousand entries and I do worry about the performance. On every new reference it needs to SELECT to check if the reference already exists.

I would really appreciate other approches or hints how to improve the query.

**EDIT:** If this can be solved with a sequence, this would be also quite nice.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if I maybe misunderstood what you mean by "solved with a sequence", but wouldn't `id` be a nice sequential reference number? And since you don't seem to store any other attribute for this (e.g. creation/import date/filename/...), and if you don't need it as a foreign key, you could simply have a single-row-single-column table and increase a counter and use this value. Although it's a little bit unclear how you are using this number, so there might be other ways. But to simply have a sequential reference, these are viable ways.

Comment: @Solarflare there is more data, I just skipped the fields. every transaction needs to have its own row, but transactions belongs together. the idea was to group those transactions by a reference number.

Comment: Presumably, there's a logical reason why the rows should be grouped together. In most cases, this would come in one of two forms: the rows are all related to another object (for instances, line items on an invoice or order), in which case the master object should have an ID for you to use; or, the rows share a common set of attributes (in which case you would normally just search on the attributes, but you might sometimes want to use a special ID value to speed searching; another table may be your best bet here, too). Do either of these match your situation?

Comment: @RDFozz unfortunately not. the table represents a ledger with transactions. some transactions belong together, like a transfer and its fee (there're other cases aswell). it would make no sense to create another "parent" table for this.

Comment: Hm. Then, maybe what you really want to do is to tie the record for the fee to the transfer record (or, the record for a reversal of a charge to the charge it's reversing, etc.). If you can identify a logical "parent" record within the ledger itself (usually going to be the first record entered, but wouldn't have to be), then, the reference ID could simply be the ID value from that parent record. How do you know that one record is a transfer and another is its fee?

Comment: @RDFozz there is a 'type' field, so i can distinguish txn types. the logical "parent" can be the first entry, but how do I find the id of the first entry, before the actual INSERT took place? the only solution I see, is to update the 'reference' field of the first row, after it was inserted.

Comment: @Aley I'm envisioning that the parent transaction would have a `NULL` `reference`, and that related additional transactions would have the parent's `id` value in `reference`. Are the additional transactions being inserted manually, or programmatically? Or, from a slightly different angle: will all the `txn` rows that need to be tied together come from a single connection, in a predetermined order; or will you potentially need to tie together a row entered today with a row entered minutes, hours, even weeks ago?

Comment: @RDFozz They will come from a single connection. I've update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As I had some time to think about it, I came up with this solution. I would appriciate a comment on this.

```
SET @ref = LAST_INSERT_ID() + 1;

INSERT INTO txn (reference) VALUES (@ref), (@ref);
```

I'm a bit worried about concurrent connections, which could result in identical reference numbers for unrelated transactions.

**EDIT:**

The upper solution will NOT work, since `LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns the last inserted ID of the current connection, which in this case will always be 0.

So another idea would be this:

```
-- This is the parent transaction
INSERT INTO txn (reference) VALUES (0);
-- Get ID of parent
SET @ref = LAST_INSERT_ID();
-- Insert related/child transactions
INSERT INTO txn (reference) VALUES (@ref), (@ref);
-- Update parent with its own ID
UPDATE txn SET reference = @ref WHERE id = @ref;
```

Comment: This will (in general) not work. `Insert` your data first (without `id`, that is what the autoincrement is for), then use `LAST_INSERT_ID` (without +1) to get the autoincrement id you just inserted. This is safe across concurrent connections. Currently, you will get the `last_insert_id` for any table (this or a different one) where you lately inserted a row using an autoincrement. Also, you don't even need the `reference` column, `id` is already that reference (if you want to keep it, update it after you inserted it).

Comment: @Solarflare Check my question again. I don't need an icremental id on every row. I need an id to group rows together to related several rows as one transaction.

Comment: @Solarflare But you are actually right, `LAST_INSERT_ID` without executing `INSERT` before, will give me just a zero, since no id was inserted on this connection previously.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I misunderstood that `txn` is the table you are actually inserting all the data into. I would strongly recomment to add a second ("parent") table, where you just insert one row for each reference id (with the proposed insert query/last_insert_id). Anything else will get you in trouble when you have concurrent connections.